# Spring Data ElasticSearch TransportClient Java Config

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Does anybody know what's Java Config equivalent of :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd">
    <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300,someip:9300"
/>
</beans>
```

I specifically want to use `nodeBuilder()` to do it.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look into Spring Data documentations for ElasticSearch:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repositories")
        static class Config {

        @Value("${esearch.port}") int port;
        @Value("${esearch.host}") String hostname;

        @Bean
        public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
         }

        @Bean
        public Client client(){
            TransportClient client= new TransportClient();
            TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostname, port); 
            client.addTransportAddress(address);
            return client;
        }
   }
```

**[Elasticsearch Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/elasticsearch.repositories.html) 2.1.2 Annotation based configuration**

> The Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories support cannot only be
>   activated through an XML namespace but also using an annotation
>   through JavaConfig.

Comment: Code above does not create a Transport Client instead it creates a Node client and is Java Config equivalent of following xml configuration

    <elasticsearch:node-client id="client" local="true"" />

Comment: Please see updated with TransportClient where you can call ElasticsearchTemplate with that constructor

Comment: also you can pass Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("","").build() to TransportClient's constructor to configure it...

Comment: Thanks Jama. That works. Is there a way to create Transport client using `nodeBuilder()`?

Comment: They are two different things. NodeBuilder creates a client for the embedded version of ElasticSearch. TransportClient is a client for externally running ES clusters.